# Razor c# code does not populate the array from a list of string values

Tags: c#, razor

```
@{
    if (Model.Cols != null)
    {
        foreach (var s in Model.Cols)
        {
            @: showcolumns.push('@s' + ':name');                
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, I am trying to insert string values each taken from the list `Model.Cols` into array `showcolumns`. But this is not actually happening. The values are not pushed into an array, although variable `s` correctly holds value each time the loop is iterated through. Would someone be able to help here?

Comment: Look at resulting html

Comment: `var showcolumns = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Cols)` (and the manipulate the values in thejavascript array

Comment: To be honest: this is ugly. Did you consider doing a simple Ajax request and get your columns array directly instead of rendering Javascript code?